# How to make a dynamic gradient effect in a dynamically generated view?

Tags: android, gradient, background-color

I have to make a gradient color effect in the view that generated dynamically according to the scenario and also the view would be of any shape (diagonal or square)[image]

As shown in image, gradient effect could be in any shape. 
Also, if I create custom view for every possible case and play with `Visibility`, then how I will manage these views to fit perfectly on every device screen size?
Just need a small help to start. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be a restriction that negative marker is forced to answer the question. Marking is easy but providing solution is not.

Answer (score 0):

> I have solved the issue using this approach.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new CustomView(this));
}
```

}

> and now create a `CustomView` class

```
public class CustomView extends View {
Rect rect;

private Rect rectangle;
private Paint paint;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int sideLength = 200;
    int sideLength1 = 100;
    rectangle = new Rect(x, y, sideLength, sideLength1);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
}

 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();

    BitmapShader shader;
    //shader = new BitmapShader(header, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    //paint.setShader(shader);

    Path path = new Path();

    path.moveTo(40,40);
    path.lineTo(5,height/2);
    path.lineTo(width/2,height/4);
    path.lineTo(width/2,0);

    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

}
```